# MS JScript runtime error, getting it randomly after 2 or 3 alerts

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Getting this exception on clicking "Ok" button on alert window.

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1 in (Some big uri)

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

It is a web application. I am have added few buttons on asp.net grid and one button click calls a popup from the server side using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "JavaScript", "alert('No notes have been saved against this customer')", true);
```

Comment: This obviously needs more details: where are you facing this, how is alert shown, is this an application/web site you are developing, etc.

Comment: Yes, it is a web application. I am have added few buttons on asp.net grid and one button click calls a popup from the server side using 

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "JavaScript", "alert('No notes have been saved against this customer')", true);

Answer (score 0):

Try adding semicolon at the end of your generated script:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "JavaScript", "alert('No notes have been saved against this customer');", true);
```

Chances are multiple scripts are getting concatenated.